# How to restrict a user list to only certain types of active users?

Tags: 2010, active-directory, user

In our SharePoint sites, we have a number of places where a user (SBS) can be inserted. For example, which user is responsible for a particular task. However, when selecting this user, there is a list of every single possible user to associate, including groups and even inactive users.

How can I restrict these user fields to only display and accept currently active user accounts?

Answer (score 1):

1. When you create the user column, make sure that the "Allow selection of:" option is set to "People Only".
   [image: Allow selection of]
2. You have the option of restricting users to a particular group.  Use the "Choose from" group to select a SharePoint group.  If you need to use an AD (Active Directory) Group then create a new SharePoint group and nest the AD group inside of it.

   [image: Choose from]
3. If you just want to exclude disabled users then you will need to do it by configuring the User Profile Service.  I have this question and answer about [how to exclude disabled users from the synchronization](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46576/how-can-i-exclude-disabled-users-from-my-user-profile-synchronization/46577#46577) which should help you out.

Comment: Awesome, yes the disabled users is the most important thing I'm trying to do. In that case, I would actually close my question as a duplicate :D